# Unable to unit test a spring service calling mocked custom repository

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spring-boot-test, spring-repositories

I defined a custom repository Interface which get stream of entities through Query.getResultStream

```
public interface MyRepository<T> {
   Stream<T> findByCriteria(...);
}

public class MyRepositoryImpl<T> implements MyRepository<T> {

   @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public Stream<T> findByCriteria(...) {
     ...
   }
}
```

and my Repository & Service

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends MyRepository<Entity> {
  ...
}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EntityService {
  @Autowired EntityRepository entityRepository;

  public Stream<Entity> getEntitiesByCriteria(String criteria) {
    ...
    return entityRepository.findByCriteria(...);
  }
}
```

Problem is my Service Unit Test does not see the repository implementation, and always return null without going inside findByCriteria implementation.

```
ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class EntityServiceTest {
  @InjectMocks EntityService service;
  @Mock EntityRepository repository;

  @Test
  void test() {
    ...
    when(repository.findByCriteria(...))
        .thenReturn(...);

    service.getEntitiesByCriteria(...); //This does not see the implementation of findByCriteria in MyRepositoryImpl

  ]
```

}

I tried many annotations like `@RepositoryDefinition` in my interface or `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my test class but nothing seems to work

Comment: With `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` it's working for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TWvn.png. So it should work with junit5 as well. Small thing I noticed is your test is not public.

Comment: Does it work if it return something else than null ? In my case even with the mock, service.getEntitiesByCriteria(...) always return null instead of the value write in thenReturn